# Google search console sitemap 404 error

Tags: sitemap

I have a problem with the sitemap in Google search console.
In the index sitemap I see al posttypes with a link to the sitemap from that posttype.

- https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-post-1.xml
- https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-page-1.xml
- **https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-product-1.xml**
- **https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-product-2.xml**
- **https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-product-3.xml**
- **https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-product-4.xml**
- **https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-product-5.xml**

I have a lot of product and Wordpress split the xml in different parts you can see above.
If I send the index sitemap called https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml to Google Search Console I get an error.

2 of the product sitemaps https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-product-4.xml and
https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap-posts-product-5.xml has an 404 error but If I browse to these hyperlinks the files are exist.

Does somebody know this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to "flush" your permalinks.

Turn the sitemap feature off, (yaost?), change your permalinks to default and back, turn on the sitemap feature again.

I like using a separate plugin to handle this instead of using Yoast. I don't like their naming convention/structure, and this issue seems to happen a lot.